# Expression resolver regex expression

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have multiple expression like

```
c1|<|5&&c2|>=|750&&c3|=|1
c1|<|5&&(c2|>=|750||c3|=|1)
c1|<|5&&(c2|>=|750||c3|=|1)&&c4|=|1
c1|<|5&&c2|>=|750||c3|=|1&&c4|=|1
(c1|<|5||c2|>=|750||c3|=|1)&&c4|=|1
```

Is there is any way we can regex expression to get the condition before each operator && and || like:

> c1|<|5&&c2|>=|750&&c3|=|1 -> (c1|<|5) && (c2|>=|750) && (c3|=|1)
>
> c1|<|5&&(c2|>=|750||c3|=|1) -> (c1|<|5) && ((c2|>=|750) || (c3|=|1))
>
> c1|<|5&&(c2|>=|750||c3|=|1)&&c4|=|1 -> (c1|<|5) && ((c2|>=|750) ||
>   (c3|=|1)) && (c4|=|1)

So ideally we should get 3 conditions in first 2 case and 4 condition in the last case. Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: @Matt.G I tried the following expression
[0-9]\\|[a-z]\\|[A-Z]|\\|\\||&&|\\(|\\)

But it gives
`[, c1|<|5, c2|>=|750, c3|=|1, , c4|=|1] for (c1|<|5||c2|>=|750||c3|=|1)&&c4|=|1`

But I want to retain operator and remove space for brackets.

Comment: @nissimabehcera this expression is throwing some exception and not working as excepted.

Comment: What language do you use ?

Comment: @nissimabehcera regexr.com/49ae3

Comment: this instead but not finished , check multi line flag

^[(]?([a-z][0-9][|](?:<[=]?|=[=]?|>[=]?)[|][0-9])[)]?(?:(?:[&]{2}|[|]{2})[(]?([a-z][0-9][|](?:<[=]?|=[=]?|>[=]?)[|][0-9]+)[)]?)*$

Comment: Is there a typo in the block that follows _like:_, where in the third line the second `&&` turns into `||`? If so, you should correct that.

Comment: What do you mean by "before". Your examples include "conditions" that come **after** the operators.

Comment: @jhnc yes that is correct. For last expression I am looking like this [c1, &&, c2, ||, c3, &&, c4]

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want but this sed command converts your sample input to your sample output:

```
sed -e 's/\&\&\|||/) & (/g;s/.*/(&)/'
```

If you want to parse the expression (for example, your several of your examples include nested parentheses, which presumably denote precedence), then you should not be using a regex engine. It is trivial to implement [Dijkstra's shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to process this type of input.

Comment: basically what I am looking for is given a expression like above I have to convert the given expression into some java model and then evaluate the expression and get the boolean result.